# Get Value from ExecuteScript from JavaScriptExecutor

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, webdriver

I have a issue i need value from

```
string someValue = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Global.Driver).ExecuteScript("$('#publication_title').val();");

Console.WriteLine(someValue);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string someValue = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Global.Driver).ExecuteScript("return $('#publication_title').val();");
```

Is what you are looking for. It needs a little more "pushing" to tell it "get this value and give it back to me".

I'd also say you probably don't even need to do this. If you are struggling to get the `value` property of an element, it's better to do:

```
element.GetAttribute("value");
```