# how to return a string from JavascriptExecutor in java

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

I'm trying to pick up the string returned from JavascriptExecutor called from Java (the first time I've ever used it).  I've seen several other posts on SO but they all stop before you get the string into Java.

Searching the internet, everybody says this should work:

```
JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
js.executeScript("return document.title");
String CatchS = js.toString();
System.out.println("Output from javascript:" + CatchS);
```

but all that I get is `Output from javascript:FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (506d8fd0-0ce2-4693-8e56-2166a77a5136)`

Which is exactly the same as you get from JavascriptExecutor if you feed it deliberately invalid JavaScript (i.e. this is it not working).

I've also tried the alternatives suggested in [Get Value from ExecuteScript from JavaScriptExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957948/get-value-from-executescript-from-javascriptexecutor), and even tried just returning 'hello world'.  Nothing works.  What am I missing?

I need it to return a string as that is what the real code I'm trying to insert will do (once it's working).  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I execute the following

```
String CatchS = (String) js.executeScript("return document.title");
```

I get an exception of

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String.
```

Comment: it said: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: Please add in a cast to string and I will accept this answer - "String CatchS = (String) js.executeScript("return document.title");" worked, thank you very much!