# Selenium javascript executor

Tags: jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this code:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
var colorCSS = js.ExecuteScript(@"jQuery('alert-danger').CSS('Background')");
```

And `colorCSS` doesn't contains bacgrounds value. Why?

If I use this jquery script in console, than it works.

Has someone any ideas?

Comment: If it would have been in java i would suggest to use `return` in your query like `return jQuery('alert-danger').CSS('Background')`, hope its same in C# too

Comment: and also check for the return type if its string u should get it in String object by appending `as string`.

Comment: Yhank You !!! You are indispensable !!!

Comment: Yes try adding return it should be same in C#

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Value from ExecuteScript from JavaScriptExecutor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957948/get-value-from-executescript-from-javascriptexecutor)

Comment: I'm sory :(  I didn't watch this.